# I am tying to build a snowflake connector for Kafka. Is there a way the connector handle events like update, delete and create?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using python connector for the transformations and pushing data to snowflake it is taking longer time for insertions into snowflake, since I have to handle transformations message by message to produce the same sequence. The existing Kafka snowflake connector can flatten the json messages but cannot handle the other events.

I am looking for faster ways to transfer and transform kafka json messages to snowflake tables.

Comment: Are you looking for something more than [Kafka Connect Transformations](https://docs.confluent.io/5.5.4/connect/transforms/index.html)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Sergiu Yes we would need transformations something like Debezium unwrap and handling create update delete events. Unfortunately Debezium  is not supporting Snowflake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options in this case IMO.

1. Write some consumer code that will transform the data from the original kafka topic (input topic) and then write it to a new topic (output topic). Then you can use the [Kafka snowflake connector](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/kafka-connector-overview.html) to write to snowflake.

or

2. Write the consumer code to do the transform and then write the data directly to snowflake in that consumer.

Option 1 has an extra step and requires using the kafka connector, so something extra to manage. Option 2 sounds like what you are currently trying. Using option 1 would allow you to leverage the community maintained snowflake connector, which is probably quite efficient. You will need to use partitions in your kafka topic to get higher throughput.

Regardless of your choice of 1. or 2. It sounds like you need to write a consumer for your kafka topic to transform the data first. In which case I would recommend you use a stream processor to do this so you do not need to manage the complexities of state, recovery and parallelism. If you are dead set on using Python, the options are [Bytewax](https://www.bytewax.io/docs) or [Faust](https://github.com/robinhood/faust). Below is some code using Bytewax to transform kafka topic data.

```
import json

from bytewax.dataflow import Dataflow
from bytewax.execution import spawn_cluster
from bytewax.inputs import KafkaInputConfig
from bytewax.outputs import KafkaOutputConfig


def deserialize(key_bytes__payload_bytes):
    key_bytes, payload_bytes = key_bytes__payload_bytes
    key = json.loads(key_bytes) if key_bytes else None
    payload = json.loads(payload_bytes) if payload_bytes else None
    return key, payload

def my_transformations(data):
    ### WRITE YOUR PYTHON TRANSFORMATION CODE HERE ###
    return data


def serialize_with_key(key_payload):
    key, payload = key_payload
    new_key_bytes = key if key else json.dumps("my_key").encode("utf-8")
    return new_key_bytes, json.dumps(payload).encode("utf-8")

flow = Dataflow()
flow.input("inp", KafkaInputConfig(
        brokers=["localhost:9092"],
        topic="input_topic",
    ),
)
flow.map(deserialize)
flow.map(my_transformations)
flow.map(serialize_with_key)
flow.capture(KafkaOutputConfig(
        brokers=["localhost:9092"],
        topic="output_topic",
    )
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    spawn_cluster(flow, proc_count = 2, worker_count_per_proc = 1,)
```

Comment: Hi Zander,  I thank you for your detailed explanations. I tried with option 1 and in my case it does not work as the existing confluent kafka snowflake connector is not capable of transforming a json data into tabular columns.  Also, If i create new topics for create, update, delete events , The sequence is messed up when i am using partitions and calling them all once.

Comment: I am currently trying with option 2 and I will explore Bytewax. Thank you for your suggestions